# Dependency newRepo:android:1.0 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I've imported a GDX project into an existing android App project and they both build fine individually. However, when I try to create an Intent to launch the GDX activity from another activity in the original app. After I add a dependency on the GDX project and import the activity class from that project I get the following build error.

`Warning:Dependency newRepo:android:1.0 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\Simon\Documents\workspace\newRepo\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk`
...

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details
```

I have read other posts mentioning that I need to change the gradle script to apply plugin library instead of application, but I couldnt find the lines mentioning apply plugin application.

Here are the two related build.gradle files.
build.grade (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'debug'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('./libs/Keys/LineTower_Debug.jks')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.towerfield"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //This is needed for Methods to be >64KB, which google play will do.
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile project(':android')
}
```

build.gradle (android)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'debug'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('./libs/Keys/LineTower_Debug.jks')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.towerfield"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //This is needed for Methods to be >64KB, which google play will do.
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile project(':android')
}
```

build.gradle (core)

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```